# Symfony2 service container: Inject array of services parameter as an argument to another service using XML

Tags: symfony

I have a parameter which should represent array of services in my `services.xml` file:

```
<parameters>
    <parameter key="decorators.all" type="collection">
        <parameter type="service" id="decorator1" />
        <parameter type="service" id="decorator2" />
        <parameter type="service" id="decorator3" />
    </parameter>
</parameters>

<services>
    <service id="decorator1" class="\FirstDecorator" />
    <service id="decorator2" class="\SecondDecorator" />
    <service id="decorator3" class="\ThirdDecorator" />
</services>
```

Now I want to inject this collection to another service as an array of services:

```
<services>
    <service id="notifications_decorator" class="\NotificationsDecorator">
        <argument>%decorators.all%</argument>
    </service>
</services>
```

But it doesn't work. Can't understand why. What am I missing?

Comment: Can't you make your decorators subscribe to a tag ? Which will call `addDecorator` of your NotificationsDecorator for each of them ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you inject array of parameters no array of services. You can inject service by service via:

```
<services>
    <service id="notifications_decorator" class="\NotificationsDecorator">
        <argument type="service" id="decorator1"/>
        <argument type="service" id="decorator2"/>
        <argument type="service" id="decorator3"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

Or (in my opinion better way) [tag](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html) `decorators` services and inject them to `notifications_decorator` during compilation passes.

**UPDATE: Working with Tagged Services**

In your case you have to modify your services like this:

```
<services>
    <service id="decorator1" class="\FirstDecorator">
        <tag name="acme_decorator" />
    </service>
    <service id="decorator2" class="\SecondDecorator">
        <tag name="acme_decorator" />
    </service>
    <service id="decorator3" class="\ThirdDecorator">
        <tag name="acme_decorator" />
    </service>
</services>
```

Additionaly you should remove `decorators.all` parameter from `<parameters>` section. Next, you have to add sth like `addDectorator` function for `\NotificationsDecorator`:

```
class NotificationsDecorator
{
    private $decorators = array();

    public function addDecorator($decorator)
    {
        $this->decorators[] = $decorator;
    }
    // more code
}
```

It would be great if you write some interface for `decorator`'s and add this as type of `$decorator` for `addDecorator` function.

Next, you have to write own compiler pass and ask them about tagged services and add this services to another one (simillarly to doc):

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class DecoratorCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->hasDefinition('notifications_decorator')) {
            return;
        }

        $definition = $container->getDefinition('notifications_decorator');
        $taggedServices = $container->findTaggedServiceIds('acme_decorator');

        foreach ($taggedServices as $id => $attributes) {
            $definition->addMethodCall(
                'addDecorator',
                array(new Reference($id))
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, you  should add your `DecoratorCompilerPass` to `Compiler` in your bundle class like:

```
class AcmeDemoBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $container->addCompilerPass(new DecoratorCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: I don't need to inject services one by one. I need to inject an array of them. Design decision. And I need to define this array as a parameter in `services.xml`, passing as arguments collection works well.

Comment: This seems to be the correct way to deal with it. Can't you consider reviewing this *"design decision"* ?

Comment: Didn't find the answer for that. It doesn't work even in yml. Seems tagging services is the best way to implement it. @NHG, can you update your answer a bit, so I can mark it as "best answer"?

Comment: @SobitAkhmedov Updated. Is it enough? Or you need more explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Little bit different approach with tagged services (or whatever you need) and `CompilerPassInterface` using array of services instead of method calls. 
Here are the differences from @NHG answer:

```
<!-- Service definition (factory in my case) -->
<service id="example.factory" class="My\Example\SelectorFactory">
    <argument type="collection" /> <!-- list of services to be inserted by compiler pass -->
</service>
```

CompilerPass:

```
/*
 * Used to build up factory with array of tagged services definition
 */
class ExampleCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    const SELECTOR_TAG = 'tagged_service';

    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $selectorFactory = $container->getDefinition('example.factory');
        $selectors = [];
        foreach ($container->findTaggedServiceIds(self::SELECTOR_TAG) as $selectorId => $tags) {
            $selectors[] = $container->getDefinition($selectorId);
        }

        $selectorFactory->replaceArgument(0, $selectors);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in yaml you can do:

```
app.example_conditions:
    class: AppBundle\Example\Conditions
    arguments:
        [[ "@app.example_condition_1", "@app.example_condition_2", "@app.example_condition_3",  "@app.example_condition_4" ]]
```

and in `AppBundle\Example\Conditions` you receive the array...

Answer (score -1):

Symfony 5.3+ and php 8.0+

```
class NotificationsDecorator
{
    private $decorators;

    public function __construct(
        #[TaggedIterator('app.notifications_decorators')] iterable $decorators
    ) {
        $this->decorators = $decorators;
    }
}

#[Autoconfigure(tags: ['app.notifications_decorators'])]
interface DecoratorInterface
{
}

class FirstDecorator implements DecoratorInterface
{
}
```